# Winsock UDP Multicast receiving with DirectShow

Tags: c++, directshow, winsock

Currently I am trying to receive multicast UDP packets inside a directshow filter on its own std::thread. I created a small function which successfully receives packets when run standalone as a console application. However, inserting this code anywhere in the directshow filter fails. (Currently using pushsource as an example starting point) Specifically, recvfrom returns -1 and WSAGetLastError() returns 10060. (tested by placing the filter on a graph with graphstudio)

This is my codeblock that creates the socket and attempts to read data from it, which is run off a std::thread.

```
char* multicast_ip = "239.1.2.3";
unsigned short multicast_port = atoi("3000");
SOCKADDR_IN multicast_addr;
WSADATA wsaData;
int hr;
BOOL bOptVal = TRUE;
ip_mreq mreq;
int max_length = 16;

WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,0), &wsaData);

SOCKET sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);

// construct bind structure
memset(&multicast_addr, 0, sizeof(multicast_addr));
multicast_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
multicast_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
multicast_addr.sin_port = htons(multicast_port);

hr = bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &multicast_addr, sizeof(multicast_addr));

/* Specify the multicast group */
mreq.imr_multiaddr.s_addr = inet_addr(multicast_ip);
/* Accept multicast from any interface */
mreq.imr_interface.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
/* Join the multicast address */
hr = setsockopt(sock, IPPROTO_IP, IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, (char FAR *) &mreq, sizeof(mreq));

int optval = 8;
hr = setsockopt(sock,IPPROTO_IP,IP_MULTICAST_TTL, (char*)&optval,sizeof(int));

hr = setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (char *)&bOptVal, sizeof(bOptVal));

int timeout = 1000; // 1 sec
setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, (char *) &timeout, sizeof(timeout));

while (true)
{
    char buffer[4096] = { 0 };

    int i = recvfrom(sock, buffer, 4096, 0, NULL, 0);

    int wut = WSAGetLastError();
}
WSACleanup();
```

Does anyone have any insights on why it would work as a standalone application but when this code is put anywhere inside the filter it fails to receive data? [The code that would actually push the data from the buffer to be handled is omitted for brevity as recvfrom doesn't return any data]

Comment: I suppose it's important how exactly you insert this code into the filter: the code itself is fine (you have it working standalone), DirectShow base does not use sockets, and then the way you get them two together - you don't show it.

Comment: Originally I merely wrapped all that code together in a function foo() and launched an std::thread pointing to foo in the constructor of my output pin. I tested it in various other places such as the filter's constructor and CreateInstance(), but both resulted in the same behavior of -1 being returned by recvfrom and winsock reporting error 10060. This occurs in a fresh pushsource example project. Is there somewhere special I should be creating the thread?